# Windows Server 2008 NPS Granular time

Tags: time, nps

Like a previous poster I am configuring NPS as a RADIUS authentication source for my wireless clients.

I need to impose a Time and Day restriction to the Network Policy that need to be more granular than can be set through the GUI (the GUI is restriced to 1 hour blocks). Ideally I would need to set the restruction to be down to 15 minute chunks - e.g to allow access from 08:30 to 17:30

I have followed a suggested solution of manually editing the ias.xml config file. This appears to work and preview of the conditions show the correct times (again using 8:30 to 17:30 as an example)

The problem is that when the times are set to 8:30 to 17:30 access is still only allowed from 08:00 to 17:00

If i set a short test access time, say 10:15 to 10:30 then no access is granted at all.

Is there any way that I can use a more granular time restriction with NPS?